# Understanding sed expression

Tags: awk, sed

I would appreciate help on the interpretation of the `sed`+`awk` command below,

```
sed -e '1,$s/ /:/g' -e '1,$s/;/:/g' |awk -F ":" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$12,$14,$18,$20,$22,$24,$26,$28,$30,$32,$34}'|sed '1,$s/ /:/g' | more
```

Comment: The majority of this is redundant. `awk -F'[: ]+' -vOFS=':'  {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$12,$14,$18,$20,$22,$24,$26,$28,$30,$32,$34}'`. Also you don't pass any files to any of the commands...

Comment: `s/don't pass/haven't passed/ `  - "don't" can be used in that context but it sounds more like an instruction than an observation.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the manual ?

However

- first sed replaces space and semicolon with colon
- awk uses colon as separator and print the first, second,  until the 34th fields, separating with space
- the last sed changes the space in colon